# Setting the thickness of the beams of tremoli in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

How can I set the thickness of tremolo beams? I use  `\override Beam.beam-thickness = #0.3` in my globals, but this sets also the thickness of beams of notes. I found this page https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/internals/stem_002dtremolo_002dinterface which says that the `stem-tremolo-interface` has a `beam-thickness` property. Is this the right thing to do, and how can I use the stem tremolo interface?
Note that I'm trying to set the thickness of a tremolo between whole notes (without stem), so `StemTremolo` isn't the right choice I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stem tremolo is for single note tremolos obtained by e.g. `c4:16`. The between note tremolo obtained by e.g. `\repeat unfold tremolo 4 { c'16 d' }` is a regular beam with a certain number of Beams floating, that is `Beam.gap-count` set to an appropriate value.

This means you cannot differentiate between non-floating "regular" beams and floating "tremolo" beams. But in case you are only using Tremolos with only floating Beams (that is total tremolo length at least 1/4th) you can use `\once\override Beam.beam-thickness = ...` to avoid changing later Beams.

In case you do need such mixed Beams you’d probably need to create your own procedure for rendering such Beams as the default implementation does not offer a hook to do so.

Comment: thank  you. How can I make such a procedure? Is it possible to combine the command above you provided with `\repeat tremolo` and always use the new command?